# How to sum the array List<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need help to sum all the integers in the arrayList and view the result of the sum in the text view, all the eight number is from edit text here is the full code that get the integer from edit text and view the sum result on the text view

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
Button button;
TextView textView;

int one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight;

int Result;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            String data = editText.getText().toString();

            one = Integer.parseInt(data.charAt(0) + "");
            two = Integer.parseInt(data.charAt(1) + "");
            three = Integer.parseInt(data.charAt(2) + "");
            four = Integer.parseInt(data.charAt(3) + "");
            five = Integer.parseInt(data.charAt(4) + "");
            six = Integer.parseInt(data.charAt(5) + "");
            seven = Integer.parseInt(data.charAt(6) + "");
            eight = Integer.parseInt(data.charAt(7) + "");


            int[] mNumber = {one, two * 2, three, four * 2, five, six * 2, seven, eight * 2};
            for (int n : mNumber) {
                spiltInt(n);
            }
        }

    });
}

public void spiltInt(int x) {
    String number = String.valueOf(x);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);
        list.add(j);
    }



}
```

}

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to achieve, can you exemplify ?

Comment: i edit the question @SchiduLuca

Comment: is there any use of Splitting the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
    //Assumig variables one,two,three,four,five,six are defined above as int
    int[] mNumber = {one, two * 2, three, four * 2, five, six * 2, seven, eight * 2};
        for (int n : mNumber) {
            spiltInt(n);
        }
       showSum(mNumber);

public void spiltInt(int x) {
    String number = String.valueOf(x);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
      int j = Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10);
      list.add(j);
     }
     int result = 0;
     for(Integer i:list){
        result+=i;
     }

      textView.setText(result+"");
  }

  public static void showSum(int[] array){
   int sum = 0;
   int digitSum = 0;
   for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
       sum+=array[i];

       String number = String.valueOf(array[i]);
       ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int j = 0; j < number.length(); j++) {
         int k = Character.digit(number.charAt(j), 10);
         list.add(k);
      }
      for(Integer digit:list){
        digitSum+=digit;
     }
   }
   //you can set any of these into test view using setText method
   System.out.println(sum+"");
   System.out.println(digitSum+"");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to sum all the digits from an array of integers, here's a 1-liner:

```
int digitSum = IntStream.of(numbers).flatMap(n -> ("" + n).chars()).map(i -> i - '0').sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `spiltInt()` which is a `non static` method and it cannot be referenced from a static context.

Just make you `spiltInt()` as `static` and call it using the class name which is 
`MainActivity` in this case.

your code becomes

```
for (int n : mNumber) {
      MainActivity.spiltInt(n);

        }
 textView.setText(result+"");
```

Now, to print the result make `result` variable global.

and use the following code at the end of your `spiltInt()` code

like

```
for(int k : list){
 result = result+k;
}
```